# Unable to put subclass objects into the list

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, activator

Would you be so kind to help me composing the method which would create a list of objects.

1. I have a class with 3 subclasses.
2. I created a method which puts all subclasses into the list.
3. Now I have problem creating the list which would contain objects - one per subclass from Step 2.
4. Please note that the list should have the parent's class type, because it will reference to the subclasses' objects polymorphicly.

Clarification:
I would like to have a list similar to

```
List<Class01> list = new List<Class01>();
list.Add(new SubClass0101());
list.Add(new SubClass0102());
list.Add(new SubClass0103());
```

but it has to **grow automatically, should the amount of subclasses increase**.

Question: I need help with **`private static IEnumerable<Type> PopulateListWithObjects<TClass>()`**

Please see code below for more details.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace PutObjectsInList
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Puts all subclasses of Class01 into the list
            var listOfSubClasses = SubClasses<Class01>();
            // Verifies that listOfSubClasses is populated with the subclasses names
            foreach (var listOfSubClass in listOfSubClasses) {Console.WriteLine(listOfSubClass);}

            var listWithObjects = PopulateListWithObjects<Class01>();

        }

        //
        private static IEnumerable<TClass> PopulateListWithObjects<TClass>()
        {
            var listWithObjects = new List<TClass>();
            // Need help with the procedure which would populate list with the
            // objects of the subclasses of the parent Class01

            return listWithObjects;
        }

        // Enumerates all subclasses for the specified class
        private static IEnumerable<Type> SubClasses<TClass>()
        {
            var subclasses =
                (from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                 from type in assembly.GetTypes()
                 where type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(TClass))
                 select type).ToList();
            return subclasses;
        }
    }

    public class Class01 {}
    public class SubClass0101 : Class01 {}
    public class SubClass0102 : Class01 {}
    public class SubClass0103 : Class01 {}
}
```

Comment: What result do you want, a list with, say, `{new SubClass0101(), new SubClass0102(), new SubClass0103()}`? Is this for a class, or is there a purpose to it?

Comment: I would like to have a list similar to 
List<Class01> list = new List<Class01>();
    list.Add(new SubClass0101());
    list.Add(new SubClass0102());
    list.Add(new SubClass0103());

Comment: Yeah, that's what I wrote. What are you going to do with that list?

Comment: The members of that list will be objects of subclasses type. Then they will have their properties assigned. After that the base class will report name of the object of the subclass type and its fields.

Comment: John, thank you very much for following through! Highly appreciate your help!

Comment: Again, what is the purpose of this? Is this a class assignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `private static IEnumerable<Type> PopulateListWithObjects<TClass>` should have return type of `IEnumerable<TClass>` if you want to achieve the desired result.

Because `Type` denotes not the object of some type, but their type - metadata identifier `System.Type`.

For creation(instantiation) of your instance you can use [Activator.CreateInstance()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

In the end it will look like:

```
    private static IEnumerable<TClass> PopulateListWithObjects<TClass>()
    {
        return ReflectorHelper.GetAndActivateAllAssignableTo<TClass>();
    }
```

With GetAndActivateAllAssignableTo defined as:

```
 public static class ReflectorHelper
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Fetches and prepares for initialization without any constructor parameters all types in the current application domain which are assignable to T.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type to which all desired types should be assignable to.</typeparam>
    /// <returns>IEnumerable of initialized objects.</returns>
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetAndActivateAllAssignableTo<T>()
    {
        return GetAndActivateAllAssignableTo<T>(null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Fetches and prepares for initialization with a given constructor parameters all types in the current application domain which are assignable to T.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type to which all desired types should be assignable to.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="consParams">The constructore parametes array - could be null</param>
    /// <returns>IEnumerable of initialized objects.</returns>
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetAndActivateAllAssignableTo<T>(object[] consParams)
    {
        //Deal with null reference for better code consistency
        if (consParams == null)
            consParams = new object[0];

        return from type in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAllAssignableTo<T>()
               where type.IsInstantiable()
               select (T)Activator.CreateInstance(type, consParams);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the flag which shows whether an object of a given type could be possibly(not guaranteed) instantiated.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type">The type to check.</param>
    /// <returns>The flag which shows whether an object of a given type could be possibly(not guaranteed) instantiated.</returns>
    public static Boolean IsInstantiable(this Type type)
    {
        if (type == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("type", "The type is null");
        if (type.IsAbstract)
            return false;
        if (type.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
            return false;
        if (type.IsInterface)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all types which are assignable to T type variables.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type to which desired types should be assignable.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="appDomain">The app domain which assemblies should be checked</param>
    /// <returns>The IEnumerable of all types which are assignable to T type variables.</returns>
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetAllAssignableTo<T>(this AppDomain appDomain)
    {
        if (appDomain == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("appDomain", "The app domain is null");
        return GetAllAssignableTo(appDomain, typeof(T));
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all types which are assignable to T type variables.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="appDomain">The app domain which assemblies should be checked</param>
    /// <param name="assignToType">The type to which desired types should be assignable.</param>
    /// <returns>The IEnumerable of all types which are assignable to T type variables.</returns>
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetAllAssignableTo(this AppDomain appDomain, Type assignToType)
    {
        if (appDomain == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("appDomain", "The app domain is null");
        if (assignToType == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("assignToType", "The type to check is null");

        return from asm in appDomain.GetAssemblies()
               from type in asm.GetExportedTypes()
               where assignToType.IsAssignableFrom(type)
               select type;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

@Tracey23 Yes, it does not exactly do what you want. It instantiates all classes that are assignable to `TClass`(!!in this code TClass can be even an interface!!), and any `TClass` is ofcourse assignable to `TClass`.

For this solution to work as you want, you may either make your Base class `abstract`, as it is doubtful that you use it in any other capacity than as base class for the components or change `GetAllAssignableTo` to use `(!assignToType.Equals(type))` in condition:

```
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetAllAssignableTo(this AppDomain appDomain, Type assignToType)
    {
        if (appDomain == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("appDomain", "The app domain is null");
        if (assignToType == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("assignToType", "The type to check is null");

        return from asm in appDomain.GetAssemblies()
               from type in asm.GetExportedTypes()
               where assignToType.IsAssignableFrom(type) && (!assignToType.Equals(type)) // !!!!!!
               select type;
    }
```

But it will change the semantics, so you may want to rename this methods to reflect that they will no longer include Base type in results.

Comment: Thank you very much, Eugene! Unfortunately, your code contains error in `public static Boolean IsInstantiable(this Type type)`
**`this`** is "Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class"

Comment: Put all this methods into separate `public static class` and it should work(I mean all from the second code snippet).

Comment: I put `public static class` within the same name space:

`    namespace PutObjectsInList
    {
        class Program ...
        public static class ReflectorHelper ...
        
        public class Class01 { }...
    }`
but I am still getting an error "The name 'GetAndActivateAllAssignableTo' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: @Tracey23 Yes, I've forgot to add `ReflectorHelper.` in the first snippet, sorry.

Comment: thank you very much! It compiled, but for some reason it put 
`[0]{PutObjectsInList.Class01} 
+[1]{PutObjectsInList.SubClass0101} 
+[2]{PutObjectsInList.SubClass0102} 
+[3]{PutObjectsInList.SubClass0103}`
 into `listWithObjects`. Nevertheless, I will work with it! Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

Start by fixing the return type.

`SubClasses<TClass>()` returns `IEnumerable<Type>` because it returns a sequence of type objects.  `PopulateListWithObjects<TClass>()` is going to return a list containing instances of a given type, so the type argument to `List<>` should be the most derived base class -- I suppose this will be `TClass`.  In other words, I think you mean

```
private static IEnumerable<TClass> PopulateListWithObjects<TClass>()
{
    var listWithObjects = new List<TClass>();

    // todo: add objects here

    return listWithObjects; 
}
```

Now how you are going to go about actually creating instances to put in the list is another question, and you haven't given enough information to answer it.

Comment: Thank you! That's absolutely correct! I updated the problem description.